# How to inverse transform the predicted values in a multivariate time series LSTM Model

Tags: python-3.x, keras, scikit-learn

I'm setting up a multivariate time series LSTM model where I use the historical data of 9 variables as my input and 3 timesteps. Dimensions of my inputs are as follows:

```
X_train_reshape  = np.reshape(X_train, (X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], 9))
X_test_reshape   = np.reshape(X_test, (X_test.shape[0], X_test.shape[1], 9))
print(X_train.shape,y_train3.shape, X_test.shape, y_test3.shape)
```

```
(1744, 3, 9) (1744, 1) (434, 3, 9) (434, 1)
```

I scaled my input to be between (0,1).

```
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
scaler = scaler.fit(train)

train = scaler.transform(train)
test  = scaler.transform(test)
```

It seems like my model is working and successfully predicting the target variables. However, I receive the following error when I try to inverse transform my target variables.

```
yhat_inv = scaler.inverse_transform(model.predict(X_train)).flatten()
```

```
"ValueError: non-broadcastable output operand with shape (1744,1) doesn't match the broadcast shape (1744,9)"
```

How can I inverse transform the predicted values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This code is for prediction of test set and inverse scaling](https://machinelearningmastery.com/multivariate-time-series-forecasting-lstms-keras/)

```
yhat = model.predict(test_X)
test_X = test_X.reshape((test_X.shape[0], test_X.shape[2]))
# invert scaling for forecast
inv_yhat = concatenate((yhat, test_X[:, 1:]), axis=1)
inv_yhat = scaler.inverse_transform(inv_yhat)
inv_yhat = inv_yhat[:,0]
# invert scaling for actual
test_y = test_y.reshape((len(test_y), 1))
inv_y = concatenate((test_y, test_X[:, 1:]), axis=1)
inv_y = scaler.inverse_transform(inv_y)
inv_y = inv_y[:,0]
# calculate RMSE
rmse = sqrt(mean_squared_error(inv_y, inv_yhat))
print('Test RMSE: %.3f' % rmse)
```